# Spring data JPA repository delete query getting fired after returning from service

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring data jpa in my spring boot application.

Below is my SchoolService method to delete school by school id.

```
    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
    public boolean deleteSchool(Long id) {
        log.debug("Deleting school entry with the school id: {}", id);
        try {
            schoolRepository.delete(id);
            return true;
        } catch(Exception e){
            log.error(e.toString());
            return false;
        }
    }
```

and my SchoolRepository is as follows.

```
public interface SchoolRepository<School, Long> extends PagingAndSortingRepository<School, Long> {


}
```

When there is some exception while deleting a school, this service method should throw an exception which should be caught and false should be returned indicating that the delete operation has failed.

But here in above case, it returns true and then it throws an exception. Not sure why?

Below is the stacktrace

```
2016-07-27 16:13:30.809 DEBUG 7650 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] c.sts.app.core.common.aop.LoggingAspect  : Enter: com.sts.app.school.service.SchoolService.deleteSchool() with argument[s] = [1]
2016-07-27 16:13:30.809 DEBUG 7650 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] c.s.a.s.service.impl.SchoolServiceImpl   : Deleting school entry with the school id: 1
Hibernate: 
    select
        school0_.id as id1_4_0_,
        school0_.created_by as created_2_4_0_,
        school0_.created_date as created_3_4_0_,
        school0_.last_modified_by as last_mod4_4_0_,
        school0_.last_modified_date as last_mod5_4_0_,
        school0_.address as address6_4_0_,
        school0_.name as name7_4_0_ 
    from
        schools school0_ 
    where
        school0_.id=?
2016-07-27 16:13:30.812 DEBUG 7650 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] c.sts.app.core.common.aop.LoggingAspect  : Exit: com.sts.app.school.service.SchoolService.deleteSchool() with result = true
Hibernate: 
    delete 
    from
        schools 
    where
        id=?
2016-07-27 16:13:30.815  WARN 7650 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1451, SQLState: 23000
2016-07-27 16:13:30.815 ERROR 7650 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`blank_app`.`students`, CONSTRAINT `FK_d8qlrs5j411ofxq8uy2nlhxm` FOREIGN KEY (`school_id`) REFERENCES `schools` (`id`))
2016-07-27 16:13:30.816  WARN 7650 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Warning Code: 1451, SQLState: 23000
2016-07-27 16:13:30.816  WARN 7650 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`blank_app`.`students`, CONSTRAINT `FK_d8qlrs5j411ofxq8uy2nlhxm` FOREIGN KEY (`school_id`) REFERENCES `schools` (`id`))
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:259)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:225)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:521)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:485)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:291)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy126.deleteSchool(Unknown Source)
    at com.sts.app.school.web.SchoolController.deleteSchool(SchoolController.java:71)
    at com.sts.app.school.web.SchoolController$$FastClassByCGLIB$$a5f9e3ee.invoke(<generated>)
```

Comment: Is is possible to add the exception stacktrace (or the relevant parts)?

Comment: @JoeG Added the stacktrace

Comment: Because the actual delete happens at flush time, and flush, unless you call it explicitely (or a query is executed whose result depend on the deletion) is done just before the transaction commit.

Comment: @JBNizet so, should I do a manual flush here ? Or should I do error handling at the controller level rather than at the service level?

Comment: @JBNizet has the correct answer.  Manual flush is probably best option too.

Comment: I would do the exception handling in the caller in that case. It's normal for a service called "deleteSchool()" to throw an exception if the deletion fails.